# access static files as well from uWSGI

Tags: python, uwsgi, openshift

I have an application (on OpenShift) which can run python. However I would also like to reach static, eg. HTML files. When try to do so I get:

> **uWSGI Error**
>
> Python application not found

Could you please help how I can make the server not to interpret all files as python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uwsgi needs a Python app to serve the URL.

As http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/HTTP.html#can-i-use-uwsgi-s-http-capabilities-in-production said:

> If you want to use it as a real webserver you should take into account that serving static files in uWSGI instances is possible, but not as good as using a dedicated full-featured web server.

In a normal case, the clients send HTTP requests to Nginx or some other web server, which handles static files' responses and leaves the rest to uwsgi.

You might be better ask that on https://serverfault.com/about